# What is faster event-based or deferred-based handling?

Tags: node.js, events, nested, deferred, promise

What is faster:

```
Event.once('some_event', function() { // wait until an event fired from somewhere
  defer.resolve('resolved')
})
...
// somewhere else
Event.emit('some_event')
```

or smth.like:

```
defer = doSmthDeferred(); // to get the deferred resolved/rejected from somewhere else
...
// somewhere else
doSmthDeferred = function() {
  defer
  if ...
    defer.resolve();
  else
    defer.reject();
}
```

I.e.: what is better - event processing or handling with nested promises/deferreds? Are promises/deferreds based on event processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much a red herring.  Speed differences between events and promise resolution are almost always going to be tiny.

Events are designed for things which happen lots of times.  e.g. Requests arriving on a webserver or users clicking a button.  They get messy when you use them for asynchronous operations as they don't support composition properly, I.e. It's difficult to wait for two events to both have happened
Promises are designed for asynchronous operations (like requesting a web page from a server).  They can only be resolved once so are not suitable for event like things.  If you have multiple asynchronous operations happening in parallel or series, promises make it really easy to compose them.  If you're looking for a good promise library I'd suggest you check out [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

Comment: Thank you! Composition property is good to know, is really great feature in promises.
I design now a module for a little project about locking/queuing messages and I cannot overcome the problem to do it in one style: promise-based, so there is a place where I need to emit an event (when one element become unlocked, I need notify a queue to grant a lock to another element in the queue, where the queue has a trigger for this event).
So is it normally or should one do only one style? How do you think?

Comment: It's fine to mix and match the two styles as appropriate in general.  Try and present a consistent interface to the outside world though.  If you feel you need both to be visible to the outside world you should probably be writing two separate modules that each do half the stuff.  Internally, for what you've described, you probably don't want a full on event system, you probably just want to define a function `processQueue` and call `processQueue` whenever an element becomes unlocked.